# vague and weak topology on separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence, borel-sets

Let $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ be Borel probability measures on a separable Hilbert space $X$.  Assume that $\mu_n\to\mu$ vaguely.  Is it necessarily true that $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly?

I know that this is true if $X$ is a locally compact Polish space (because enlargements of compacta stay compact and we can get tightness, see below) .  I have only seen the vague topology used on locally compact spaces so I suspect that things behave badly outside this setting.

**A related question in case the answer is "no":** denote the set of Borel probability measures on $X$ by $P(X)$.  Is it at least true that the Borel sigma algebras generated from the vague and weak topologies on $P(X)$ are equal?  I wanted to use something like the Lusin-Suslin theorem (11.4 [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jsr25/Spring_11/Lecture_Notes/dst_lecture_notes_2011_image-Borel.pdf)) but the vague topology is not complete when restricted to probability measures.

Proof when $X=\mathbb R^d$:  let $K_1$ compact such that $\mu(K_1)>1-\epsilon$.  Let $K_2=\{x:\|x - K_1\|\le \epsilon\}$, which is also compact.  There exists a continuous function $0\le f\le 1$ with $f\equiv1$ on $K_1$ and $f\equiv0$ outside $K_2$.  Then
$$
\mu_n(K_2)
\ge \int fd\mu_n
\to \int fd\mu
\ge \mu(K_1)
$$
is larger then $1-2\epsilon$ for $n$ large.  Since $K_2$ is compact $(\mu_n)$ is tight, has a weak limit, and that limit has to be $\mu$.  This is easily extended to any locally compact space instead of $\mathbb R^d$ with a more painful construction of the set $K_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no. In fact, for any $\mu_n,\mu\in P(X)$, $\mu_n\to\mu$ vaguely. This comes from the fact that $C_0(X)=0$.

To see this, assume $f\in C_0(X)$. For each $n$, there exists a compact set $K_n$ such that $|f|\le\frac1n$ outside $K_n$. Recall that compact sets in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces have empty interior, and hence are nowhere dense. Defining $K:=\bigcup_nK_n$, we have that $K$ is nowhere dense by the Baire category theorem. But $f=0$ outside of $K$, and hence $f\equiv0$.

This is why you never see the vague topology discussed outside of the context of a locally compact space - without the assumption of local compactness, it may be entirely meaningless.

Comment: The conclusion is correct, but the argument is slightly wrong.  Baire category says that $K$ has empty interior, but it need not be nowhere dense ($K$ need not be closed, and its closure could have nontrivial interior).  But anyway you don't need Baire here: for each $n$ the set $\{|f| > 1/n\}$ is both open and contained in $K_n$, so it must be empty because, as you said, $K_n$ has empty interior.  Hence you have $|f| \le 1/n$ everywhere, and $n$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you both for this discussion.  I did not write this earlier because I did not have enough reputation for writing comments.